# Accessing matrix elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I got used to working in IDLE, but got a recommendation to use PyCharm instead.

As I'm just getting used to it, I have a question on accessing elements of a matrix.

I'm getting different string inputs from the user and filling the matrix with them;

```
from numpy import *

row=int(input())
col=int(input())

m=range(row*col)
m=reshape(m,(row,col))

for i in range(0,row):
    for j in range(0,col):
        el=int(input())
        m[i][j]=el
```

What PyCharm is telling me:

Class 'ndarray' does not define '**getitem**', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances less... 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Could anyone please explain to me how I can change/fix this?

Comment: Believe PyCharm.  It's smarter than IDLE, you, or me.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of exactly where this issue is showing up, as I am not getting the same issue (although I have seen this before)...

Comment: I do believe it, I just don't feel like being bombarded with warnings/errors that I would never get in IDLE. Still, I see that PyCharm has its perks so I guess I'll learn to take advantage of them with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the vanilla `range` object in Python.  It looks like you want to use the `numpy.arange` operation instead which creates a NumPy array for you.  `range` does not give you what `numpy.arange` does.

You need to change that statement to use `arange`:

```
m=arange(row*col)
```

The reason why PyCharm is probably giving you that error is because you are implicitly converting from one type to another.  This is due to their [type hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) mechanism so it's good practice to produce the expected output immediately when you produce the array with `arange`.

However, this is quite superfluous as you are creating a `row x col` 2D array that is linearly increasing, but you end up replacing all of the elements anyway.  Consider pre-allocating the matrix with `numpy.zeros` of the desired size instead:

```
m = zeros((row, col))
```

Also, it is very bad practice to do this: `from numpy import *`.  This is because you may be importing other packages that could share the same function names between packages.  Unless you absolutely know that doing the above style of import won't provide any conflicts, I would not recommend you do this.  Instead, import NumPy with the alias `np` as many people do so:

```
import numpy as np
```

After, call any NumPy functions by accessing `np`:

```
import numpy as np

row=int(input())
col=int(input())

m=np.range(row*col)
m=np.reshape(m,(row,col))
# or:
# m = np.zeros((row, col))

for i in range(0,row):
    for j in range(0,col):
        el=int(input())
        m[i][j]=el
```

Comment: Thank you, i like the idea of creating a zero matrix instead!

Comment: Interesting, I got " Unsolved reference 'zeros' " warning... I'm wondering if PyCharm has some sort of an issue with importing as I'm only getting half the functionality of numpy

Comment: It's very bad practice to do `from numpy import *`.  It's best if you import the package with an alias: `import numpy as np`, then use `np` to access the functionality of NumPy.

Comment: I'm now getting " Cannot find reference 'zeros' ". Tried importing numpy again and confirmed it's already imported

Comment: Running it was successful though!

Comment: @frostpad Restart PyCharm and change the import call to `import numpy as np`.  I believe your workspace has been already polluted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
from numpy import np
row=int(input())
col=int(input())
m = []
for i in range(0,row):
    for j in range(0,col):
        el=int(input())
        m.append(el)
m=np.reshape(m,(row,col))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, in IDLE, and `ipython`:

```
In [178]: row=3
     ...: col=2
     ...: 
     ...: m=range(row*col)
     ...: m=np.reshape(m,(row,col))
     ...: 
     ...: for i in range(0,row):
     ...:     for j in range(0,col):
     ...:         el=int(input())
     ...:         m[i][j]=el
     ...: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
In [179]: m
Out[179]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

If `pycharm` objects, it's because it's looking at style as much as syntax.  I don't use it, so can't say how well it handles `numpy` constructs.

I would use `np.arange(row*col).reshape(row,col)` to generate `m`, but your use of `range` and `reshape` works as well.  Actually since you are filling in all values from user input, `m = np.zeros((row,col),int)` works just as well.

Iterative input like that is slow and clumsy, but at least you aren't trying to use `np.append`.

The double indexing might be a problem for pycharm.

```
m[i][j] = e1    # works
m[i, j] = e1    # better
```

I have no idea why `pycharm` is complaining that `'ndarray' does not define 'getitem'.

```
In [184]: m.__getitem__
Out[184]: <method-wrapper '__getitem__' of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7fe7e883e350>
```

It may just be that `pycharm` is objecting to `[i][j]`, but for rather convoluted reasons.  I'd try the `[i,j]` syntax and see if the complaint goes away.

Comment: I tried [i,j] but it didn't work, unfortunately. Thank you for checking it in IDLE though, I have to admit I miss using it.